# How to trigger LiveData SwitchMap even if there is no observer attached

Tags: android, rx-android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

**Issue:**

The switchMap transformation does not trigger until its result must have an active observer. I am trying to trigger a switchMap transformation even if there is no observer. Can anyone suggest how i can achieve this functionality? There is some code below with depicting the current scenario.

**How to reproduce:**

In ProfileViewModel, The UI can observe two different LiveData

- **profileLiveData** : to observe Profile Data
- **profileApiStateLiveData** : to observe the state of Http Call that fetches the profile data from backend

**ProfileViewModel.java**

```
public class ProfileViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> getProfileCommand = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public ProfileViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        profileLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(getProfileCommand, forceUpdate -> UserRepository.getInstance().getProfile(forceUpdate));
        profileApiStateLiveData = UserRepository.getInstance().getProfileApiRequestStatus();
    }

    public void loadProfile(boolean forceUpdate) {
        getProfileCommand.postValue(forceUpdate);
    }

    // Profile Data : Observable Field
    private LiveData<Profile> profileLiveData;
    public LiveData<Profile> getProfileLiveData() {
        if(profileLiveData == null) profileLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        return profileLiveData;
    }

    // Profile Http Call's State : Observable Field
    private LiveData<ApiRequest>  profileApiStateLiveData;
    public LiveData<ApiRequest>  getProfileApiStateLiveData() {
        if(profileApiStateLiveData == null) profileApiStateLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        return profileApiStateLiveData;
    }
}
```

Now the UI can observe changes in both Profile Data and State of Http Call. 
So if a UI want to download and display the Profile on UI, the UI is responsible to observe the **profileLiveData** and **profileApiStateLiveData** and then call the ViewModel's method ***loadProfile(true);***

```
// Observes Profile Data
mProfileViewModel.getProfileLiveData().observe(this, profileData -> {
    // Use profile data here
});

// Observes State of Profile Http Call
mProfileViewModel.getProfileApiStateLiveData().observe(this, profileHttpCallState -> {
    // show/hide progress based on http call state
});

// start downloading profile data
mProfileViewModel.loadProfile(true);
```

We can see here that the method **loadProfile** will trigger the switchMap Transformation and will start the Http Call. Please note that switchMap trigger happens because the UI is observing the result LiveData which is **profileLiveData**.

This scenario works fine. But if a certain Activity only wants to initiate the Http Call and only want to observe the **profileApiStateLiveData** not the **profileLiveData**, then the switchMap Trigger never occur, this is because there is no active observer of result LiveData **profileLiveData**.

```
    /**** Do not observe Profile Data, because here we only need to observe Http Call State  ***/

    /**** Only Observe State of Profile Http Call  ***/
    mProfileViewModel.getProfileApiStateLiveData().observe(this, profileHttpCallState -> {
        // show/hide progress based on http call state
    });

    /**** start downloading profile data ***/
    mProfileViewModel.loadProfile(true);

    /**** The above line does not trigger the switchMap Transformation. ***/
```

There is an ugly solution i have in which i have to add an un-necessary blank observer for **profileLiveData** in the UI. But that is error-prone because the other developers can forget to add this un-necessary blank observer for **profileLiveData** and they would have no clue about why profile data is not being fetched even they are calling the method ***loadProfile(true)***.

> The help from Rx experts is much appreciated here :-)

Comment: Not sure why you would like to design both LiveData in this way. On fetching the data why dont you update `profileLiveData` and `profileApiStateLiveData`. Or if you have a database layer which emits LiveData map `profileLiveData` directly with it?

Comment: Both of these LiveData are coming directly from Room Database. The http layer(WorkManager) is updating these table records separately.

Comment: Then I would have `profileLiveData` emit data directly from the DB instead of emitting data when `profileApiStateLiveData` changes. When data in DB changes `profileLiveData` should emit the new data.
`profileApiStateLiveData` should only emit changes on change in API state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered very well and thanks to @arka-prava-basu . The **profileLiveData** has been detached from Transformation and it is now being fetched directly from Room Database. And the action

> (UserRepository.getInstance().getProfile(forceUpdate) )

that was being performed by this transformation has been now transferred to **loadProfile** method. Below is the refactored code.

**ProfileViewModel.java**

```
public class ProfileViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

   public ProfileViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        profileLiveData = UserRepository.getInstance().getMemberInfo();
        profileApiStateLiveData = UserRepository.getInstance().getProfileApiRequestStatus();
    }

    public void loadProfile(boolean forceDownload) {
        if(forceDownload) {
            UserRepository.getInstance().initiateProfileDownloading();
        }
    }

    // Profile Data : Observable Field
    private LiveData<Profile> profileLiveData;
    public LiveData<Profile> getProfileLiveData() {
        return profileLiveData;
    }

    // Profile Http Call's State : Observable Field
    private LiveData<ApiRequest>  profileApiStateLiveData;
    public LiveData<ApiRequest>  getProfileApiStateLiveData() {
        return profileApiStateLiveData;
    }
}
```